# Incrementally build data structures which reference the same data

Tags: rust

I have an `EntityMap` object which deals with spatially indexing anything that can have a bounding box. I've implemented it in such a way that it stores references to objects rather than owned values (this may not be the best way to do, but I think changing it to owned values would only shift my problem).

What I am currently attempting to do is add objects to a vector in such a way that they do not collide with anything that was previously added to the vector. The following is pseudo-rust of what I just described:

```
let mut final_moves = Vec::new();
let mut move_map = EntityMap::new();
for m in moves.into_iter() {
    let close_moves = move_map.find_intersecting(m.bounding_box());
    let new_move = m.modify_until_not_intersecting(close_moves);
    final_moves.push(new_move);
    move_map.insert(final_moves.last().unwrap());
}
```

`final_moves` is what is being returned from the function. The issue here is that I'm mutably borrowing `final_moves`, but I want to store references to its objects inside `move_map`. The conflict I can't figure out how to resolve is that I want to incrementally build `final_moves` and `move_map` at the same time, but this seems to require that they both be mutable, which then stops me from borrowing data from `move_map`.

How do I restructure my code to accomplish my goals?

Answer (score 0):

You could change the types of `move_map` and `final_moves` to contain `Rc<Move>` instead of just `Move`.

```
let mut final_moves = Vec::new();
let mut move_map = EntityMap::new();
for m in moves.into_iter() {
    let close_moves = move_map.find_intersecting(m.bounding_box());
    let new_move = Rc::new(m.modify_until_not_intersecting(close_moves));
    final_moves.push(Rc::clone(new_move));
    move_map.insert(new_move);
}
```